# Flutter android Codemagic failed since the latest flutter version?

Tags: android, flutter, codemagic

After the latest flutter update(3.10.1) codemagic stops generating apks

Answer (score 0):

Just use another old flutter version in my case it was(3.7.3) that worked on codemagic
[image]